# MongoDb : Storing aggregates and domain events atomically

Tags: mongodb, domain-driven-design

I'm using DDD and MongoDb for the underlying storage.
I'm not using event sourcing. I need to persist the aggregate's state and domain events it's publishing in the same transaction, before publishing those events elsewhere - for resilience reasons.

Mongo allows transactions but only in replica sets configuration.
How can I achieve the same level of resilience without mongo transactions?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the usual answer is that you store the domain events in the same document that stores the aggregate state (a single representation that includes all of the information you need for both).

See [Data on the Outside vs Data on the Inside](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf), by Pat Helland.